# Desktop gets choppy after suspend

Tags: linux, debian, awesome-wm

My old gaming laptop with 8 cores and 8GB mem gets unbearably slow in user experience after resuming from suspend - sometimes. In this state, video playback would give me about one static picture every second - 1 fps is not how I watch movies, usually... Scrolling and navigating websites gets very sticky and annoying.

I squeeze all the power and utility from it using Awesome WM and minimal Debian Buster installation with hand picked software. When it is not affected by the resume trouble, it just rocks.

I've searched and most resources pointed to CPU frequency or scheduler being messed up after resume so I installed cpupower, gkrellm... and investigated cpufreq-info and all that. No luck. Frequency was moving as needed with the ondemand or performance scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I stumbled upon an [old bug reported agains Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/676413). This led me to think about my compositing manager - **unagi**. This is a **rather dangerously aged**, but still a fine piece of software that does just what I want. However it seems to be the culprit of the resume trouble. Simply restarting it gives me back all the power. I've yet to try the trick with process scheduling to narrow this down:

> Running `sudo chrt -r -p 20 [pid of X]` solves the problem for me, while
>   resetting with `sudo chrt -o -p 0 [pid of X]` restores the performance
>   issues.

I will update here when I do.

While this kind of solves the problem, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Eww, Unagi has (had?) a non-zero user count! That's a surprise to me, But yes, Unagi has many bugs and is an abandonateware for nearly a decade. The current most popular stand alone compositor is called "picom". Given the long list of issues with Unagi, I would not advise to use it. Picom is active and well maintained.

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelLepageVallee, I've looked at it and will try it out. I picked Unagi earlier because of the really tiny footprint, probably also judging by the number of dependencies. It is a pity, I looked at the Unagi code and to a non C developer point of view, it doesn't actually look scary :D

Comment: Actually why not make picom an answer?